# Recover database from uninstalled SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, recovery

My SQL Server was accidentally uninstalled. I didn't take a backup of all the databases. Is it possible to recover them?

Answer (score 5):

The database files are probably still there - in the directory for data and log files.

Th default one is `c:\ProgramFiles\MSSQL\MSSQL\MSSQL10_50\MSSQL\Data`.
If not default then you need to locate your files and attach them to SQL Server instance of the same or higher edition.

Comment: try a search with *.mdf *.ndf

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can

Go to "`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA`", here you can see your old db MDF and LDF Fils. and you can open those file in sql server as you used earlier.

Step 1 :
     Open SQL Management Studio

Step 2 :
     Open Connection

Step 3 :
     Right click on the "Database" folder and Click "Attach"

Step 3 :
     Click add Button and go to "`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA`"

Step 4 :
     Select your Database MDF file and Click Ok

Hope You are done